# java: output for quadratic equation tool

Tags: java, output, equation

I'm working on a java application that will allow users to input data (a, b, and c for ax^2 + bx + c = 0) so that calculations will be conducted and the solution will be displayed for users on the screen (specifically, it will solve for x-plus and x-minus).

I think I'm on the right track with the code below (which, of course, means that I will be found to be wrong about that, haha), but I can't seem to figure out how to properly display the x-plus and x-minus after the calculations have been conducted.

I think I'm uncertain of the placement for the code for one thing (e.g., before or after placement of calculations; I tried both ways and was wrong each time). I also wonder if importing JOptionPane was really the way to go for this task.

Here's what I have so far. Any advice?

```
package a3main;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class A3main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    String input;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for a:  ");
    a = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for b:  ");
    b = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for c:  ");
    c = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

}

private double XPlus (double a, double b, double c){
    return ((-b) + Math.sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
}

private double XMinus (double a, double b, double c) {
    return ((-b) - Math.sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / ( 2 * a);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this to show your value:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your text: " + your value);
```

You can also add this to get a new line:

```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your text: " + yourValue + "\n" + "Anoter text:" + anotherValue);
```

On your code, you have to add it to the end of the input if you want to see all the results of your inputs, if not,you have to add it after each input.

This is an example at the end:

```
package a3main;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class A3main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int a;
int b;
int c;
String input;

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for a:  ");
a = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for b:  ");
b = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your value for c:  ");
c = (int) Double.parseDouble(input);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A value: " + a + "\nB value:" + b + "\nC value:" + c);

}

private double XPlus (double a, double b, double c){
    return ((-b) + Math.sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
}

private double XMinus (double a, double b, double c) {
    return ((-b) - Math.sqrt(( b * b) - (4 * a * c))) / ( 2 * a);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried something like this earlier and think it would have worked had I known where to place it correctly. Do you have advice on where either of these codes would appear within my code?

Comment: @J'onJ'onzz i edited my response to show you an example

Answer (score 0):

You can also give information via `System.out.println(xPlus(a, b, c));` and then call `xMinus` as well. This prints out the information you want to `System.out`.

The other answer deals with doing this with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a single pane program that does exactly what you need done:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class A3main {
private static Component frame;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  JTextField a = new JTextField(5);
  JTextField b = new JTextField(5);
  JTextField c = new JTextField(5);
  JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("a value:");
  JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("b value:");
  JLabel cLabel = new JLabel("c value:");
  JLabel calculatedLabel = new JLabel("Calculated:");    
  JLabel calculatedNum = new JLabel("0.0");    
  JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

  myPanel.add(aLabel);
  myPanel.add(a);
  myPanel.add(bLabel);
  myPanel.add(b);
  myPanel.add(cLabel);
  myPanel.add(c);
  myPanel.add(calculatedLabel);
  myPanel.add(calculatedNum);
  myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));


//creating icon
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://iconizer.net/files/Devine_icons/thumb/128/Calculater.png"));

//variable declarations    
double aNum = 0;
double bNum = 0;
double cNum = 0;
boolean invalidInput = false;
String Answer = "";
boolean restart = true;
Object[] mainOptions = {"Exit","Calculate","Copy answer"};


while(restart){
    //user input
    int mainPanel = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, myPanel, 
       "Quadratic Equation Calculator", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        icon, mainOptions, mainOptions[1]);

    if(mainPanel==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(Answer);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);               
    }else if(mainPanel==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            invalidInput = false;
        try{
            aNum = Double.parseDouble(a.getText());
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            invalidInput = true;
            calculatedLabel.setText(""); 
            calculatedNum.setText("Invalid a value");                    
        }try{
            bNum = Double.parseDouble(b.getText())/100;
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            invalidInput = true;
            calculatedLabel.setText(""); 
            calculatedNum.setText("Invalid b value");                    
        }try{
            cNum = Double.parseDouble(c.getText());
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            invalidInput = true;
            calculatedLabel.setText(""); 
            calculatedNum.setText("Invalid c value");                    
        }

        //calculating answer
        double b2 = bNum*bNum;
        double inSqrt = b2 - (4 * aNum * cNum);
        double ans1 = (((bNum*(-1)) - java.lang.Math.sqrt(java.lang.Math.abs(inSqrt))) / ( 2 * aNum));
        double ans2 = (((bNum*(-1)) - java.lang.Math.sqrt(java.lang.Math.abs(inSqrt))) / ( 2 * aNum))*-1;

        //converting answer to string format
        Answer = "+: "+ans1+", -: "+ans2;

        if(!invalidInput){
            calculatedLabel.setText("Calculated:"); 
            calculatedNum.setText(Answer);
        }
    }else{
        System.exit(0);               
    }           
}
} // main string
} // public class
```